# Replace with hex character

Tags: substitute, ex-mode, ex-command

Given this file:

```
printf 'hello\x19world\n' > hello.txt
```

I can replace a hex character:

```
$ ex -sc '%s/\%x19/ /|x' hello.txt
$ od -c hello.txt
0000000   h   e   l   l   o       w   o   r   l   d  \n
```

However I cannot replace with a hex character:

```
$ ex -sc '%s/ /\%x19/|x' hello.txt
$ od -c hello.txt
0000000   h   e   l   l   o   %   x   1   9   w   o   r   l   d  \n
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `:help todo`:

> Substitute with hex/unicode number "\%xff" and "\%uabcd".  Just like
>       "\%uabcd" in search pattern.

In other words, this isn't implemented yet.

You can do it interactively, in Vim.  See `:help 24.8`.

Type `:%s/ /`, then type `Ctrl-V`, then `x19`, then press Enter.

Comment: Most shells allow a similar input mechanism

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this easily. You just have to use an expression in the replacement part (see the help at `:h sub-replace-expression` [link](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)).

So you would do it like this:

```
ex -sc '%s/ /\="\x19"/g|x' hello.txt
 od -c hello.txt
 0000000   h   e   l   l   o 031   w   o   r   l   d  \n
```

See the help at `:h expr-quote` [link](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-quote)

Comment: Sorry, but all that does it remove the space for me

Comment: what vim version?

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4

Comment: please show the complete output

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it from the shell:

```
ex -sc $'%s/\031/\027/|x' hello.txt
```

This will pass the literal `^Y` and `^[` characters to `ex`, which seems to work fine. You can also enter a literal character as `^V^Y` (control+v control+y) in most shells.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a solution:

```
:s/\%x19/ /g
```

TIP: The value `\x19` can be expressed on Unicode by `\u0019`. So you can do:

```
:s/ /\="\u0019"/g
```

When you press `ga` you can see the hex value, if it has less than four digits fill it with zeros and you have the Unicode value

For example `Xex 20` (space), can be `\u0020` and in the search pattern we have to use backslash + percent + (u|x|o) followed by its number.

On the substitution portion, you have to use an expression register if we want to use any (unicode|hex|octal) replacement.